# is Kolmogorov complexity computable on a finite domain?

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity

The [proof in the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Uncomputability_of_Kolmogorov_complexity) for the uncomputability of Kolmogorov complexity uses the fact that there are strings of arbitrarily large Kolmogorov complexity. What if we restrict to a finite domain so this no longer holds? Specifically, what if I am only interested in strings of length $\le N$, is there an algorithm $M_N$ for computing Kolmogorov complexity for all these strings? As long as
$$
|M_N| \ge max \{K(s)| s \in \Sigma^i, i \le N\}\,,
$$
it seems like it would at least escape the contradiction from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes", i.e., for every *fixed* $N$, there is an algorithm $M_N$ that, given an input string $s$ (on some fixed alphabet $\Sigma$) of length at most $N$, returns the Kolmogorov complexity of $s$. You might find the argument a bit unsatisfactory though, as it is not constructive.

Let $s_1, s_2, \dots$ be the strings in $\bigcup_{i=0}^N \Sigma^i$  and let $k_i$ be the Kolmogorov complexity of $s_i$.
$M_N$ determines which of the (finitely many) strings $s_i$ matches the input string, and returns $k_i$. Notice this approach only works because the set of input strings for which we need to answer correctly is finite (since algorithms are required to have a finite amount of instructions).

Comment: More generally, **anything** is computable on a finite domain.

Comment: Thanks, you're right it's a bit unsatisfying though. If $M_N$ is just a lookup table, doesn't this mean we need to know all the $k_i$'s in advance?

Comment: Yeah, essentially $M_N$ just consults a lookup table. You don't need to know the $k_i$s to show the *existence* of $M_N$, you just need to show that there is *some* choice of $k_i$ that makes the algorithm work. In your problem the input is $s$, $|s|\le N$ and the output is $K(s)$. You might be thinking of the problem of finding $M_N$. There the input would be $N$ and the output would be a description of an algorithm $M_N$ that, on input $s$, $|s|\le N$ returns $K(s)$. The latter problem is clearly undecidable since it allows you to find $K(s)$ of any string $s$ by first computing $M_{|s|}$.

Comment: Yes, I guess the problem of finding $M_N$ is what I'm thinking of. Could the same not be said about this problem though? The only reason this is clearly uncomputable is that now $N$ is unbounded, but suppose I only want to be able to find $M_N$ for all $N$ up to some fixed number?

Comment: Then the same strategy still works, there is an algorithm that takes in input $N$ and consults a lookup table to output $M_N$. As soon as $N$ is not upper bounded by some fixed constant then the problem becomes undecidable again.

Comment: Sure, but then we are no longer capturing the notion of being able to practically obtain the algorithm from my original question because, again, I'd need to already know all the $M_N$'s in order to define this second algorithm What I want to know is, can I ever write down this algorithm and be sure it's right? or is it impossible that I ever write down this algorithm and be sure that it's right?